# How to get started with creating a database using pointer and memory allocation

Tags: c, database, pointers, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have an assignment where I have to create a song database with 3 inputs (Song name, duration and copyright). Our professor instructed us to use pointers to make linked lists and to use malloc, calloc and free. I am not looking for exact answers but I'm looking for how to go about doing this. I have never touched memory allocation in my life so it's something new that I have to learn.

How should I start with the program? Should I create a new .txt that the program should write to when adding a new entry?

The program should let the user enter an unknown number of songs including their duration and copyright. Using structs in a singly linked list, allocate each node using malloc. The program should print the database in the reverse order (from being entered) at any time.

Comment: Can we start with what context you know about this? Without having some idea of how much of this you already get, it's hard to give a good answer.

Comment: I am able to read and write to an external file and changing the data within. Structs are very simple for me and I have no problem using them. However pointers are not my strong point. It takes me a while figure them out and I still don't understand them. Like I said, I have no idea about memory allocation.